# Java simple JSON object declaration throws exception

Tags: java, json, exception

I have a super simple line:

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": { \"barcode\": \"testing\" } }");
```

Android studio tells me that this line 'throws JSONException', but why? I must be doing something stupid here. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does it actually throw the exception at runtime (if so, what is the error message) or is this just a compile-time error (asking you to catch or rethrow a JSONException that might happen)?

Comment: @Thilo this is a compile time error

Comment: That JSONObject constructor has the possibility to throw that error so you need to deal with it (catch) even when you know "it can't happen".

Answer (score 3):

[JSONException](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html) is a checked exception. This means that you need to have code in place to deal with it. You need to either `catch` the exception or let it bubble up by declaring `throws JSONException` on your method.

This is the case for all checked exceptions in Java (all exception except those that extend RuntimeException).

In your case, since the String is constant and correct, I would do

```
   } catch ( JSONException e) {
      // should never happen
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected parsing error",e);
   }
```

This will convert the JSONException (if for some reason it does happen after all) into an (unchecked) RuntimeException.

Answer (score 1):

```
public JSONObject(String source) throws JSONException {
        this(new JSONTokener(source));
    }
```

You are using above method/constrcutor to create your JSONObject and its saying in its signature that it throws `JSONException` so you can't simply do what you have done ,

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": { \"barcode\": \"testing\" } }");
```

You need to enclose above line in Java `try- catch`  since method signature is clearly specifying a **checked Exception** so you need to handle that in try catch.

```
try{
JSONObject params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": { \"barcode\": \"testing\" } }");

}catch(JSONException ex){
 //eat or rethrow your exception
}
```

You have to note that there are other `JSONObject` constructors which doesn't specify any checked exceptions so you can use those in a simple line, like you did but the one you are trying to use specifies a checked exception so you need to handle that - otherwise your code won't compile.